# Cypher Query to find out my followers and users i follow?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi my relations are like this i---follows----someone, someelse---follows----me , What will be the cypher query ? Problem is that im not able to figure out which is the end node .

Comment: Please edit your question to show what cypher query you've tried, and what you mean by *end node* (since your relationship example shows no directionality). It would be helpful to reform the relation with cypher syntax to show directionality.

Answer (score 3):

There are no directions specified in your questions so I hope I guessed them right, but if not, just modify as needed:

Find who you follow:

```
START n=node(yourNodeID) MATCH n-[:follows]->person RETURN person;
```

Find who follows you:

```
START n=node(yourNodeID) MATCH person-[:follows]->n RETURN person;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , i found the solution. We can do like this START n=node(MYnodeId) MATCH n-[r:follows]-person RETURN startNode(r),endNode(r);